# How to populate a new column with the value associated with a specified timestamp?

Tags: python, pandas

My df looks something like this

```
Date Time,Raw RMY Pad 7,RMY Pad 7 previous,difference,RMY Pad 7
2020-05-15 00:15:00,0.028,Nan,Nan,Nan
2020-05-16 00:15:00,0.028,0.028,0.0,0.028
2020-05-17 00:15:00,0.030,0.028,0.002,0.030
2020-05-18 00:15:00,0.050,0.030,0.02,0.050
```

and I would like to add a row and populate it with the value of whatever 'Date Time' I specify. So for example if I were to specify,

```
start_date = '2020-05-15'
```

the new column would be populated with 0.028. And if I were to specify,

```
start_date = '2020-05-17'
```

the new column would be populated with 0.030. I would like to do this to "zero" the dataframe based on the selected start date. So basically would be

```
zeroed RMY pad 7 = start_date 'value' - baseline 'value'
```

I have a number of dataframes that I am comparing that I would like to use this with.

In the end I would like the following df,

```
start_date = '2020-05-15'

Date Time,Raw RMY Pad 7,RMY Pad 7 previous,difference,RMY Pad 7,baseline,zeroed RMY pad 7
2020-05-15 00:15:00,0.028,Nan,Nan,Nan,Nan,Nan
2020-05-16 00:15:00,0.028,0.028,0.0,0.028,0.028,0.0
2020-05-17 00:15:00,0.030,0.028,0.002,0.030,0.028,0.002
2020-05-18 00:15:00,0.050,0.030,0.02,0.050,0.028,0.022
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the baseline value for a given date you should set the index to the `'Date Time'` column and then use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html). We use only the `date` part for the comparison.

```
df['zeroed RMY pad 7'] = df['Raw RMY Pad 7'] - df.set_index(df['Date Time'].dt.date).loc[pd.to_datetime(start_date).date(),'Raw RMY Pad 7']
```

Result for `start_date = '2020-05-15'`:

```
            Date Time  Raw RMY Pad 7 RMY Pad 7 previous difference RMY Pad 7  zeroed RMY pad 7
0 2020-05-15 00:15:00          0.028                Nan        Nan       Nan             0.000
1 2020-05-16 00:15:00          0.028              0.028        0.0     0.028             0.000
2 2020-05-17 00:15:00          0.030              0.028      0.002     0.030             0.002
3 2020-05-18 00:15:00          0.050              0.030       0.02     0.050             0.022
```